# Will + have + V3 + before

Tags: meaning

I encountered this sentence and the word "before" disappointed me. Can you explain why there is the future tense and this word in the end. If the meaning of "before" is "after your back or in the past" it can't be with future tense.
The sentence: Here's some really nice cheese that I don't think you will have tasted before.
Thanks.

Comment: True, this is confusing.  But *before* means in the past, just as you expect.  The *will* in there is the hard part.  It is **not** showing the future.

Comment: It's one of those sentences that make perfect sense to a native speaker but are hard to explain. The sense is "When you taste the cheese, I think you _will find_ that it is a kind that _you have not tasted before [now]_.

Comment: No modal verb can mean only one thing in English, including *will*.  Here it means probability not futurity. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: There is no future tense in the sentence to begin with. *Will* is the present tense. English does not have a future tense. Yes, "will" can sometimes refer to the future. But so can "am". That alone is not sufficient to assume that "am" is always in the future tense. You are going to run into huge problems if you do that. So don't. Don't assume it about "am", and don't assume it about "will".